# How to use SDL_MapRGB with SDL 2.0

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I am trying to get a 24-bit color from rgb values. I want to use `SDL_MapRGB`, but I don't know what pixel format is. Since its SDL 2.0 I am using the `SDL_Window` and `SDL_Renderer`.

Answer (score 4):

```
SDL_Surface* surface = //however you created your surface
SDL_PixelFormat* myPixelFormat=surface->format;
```

This is from the page https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PixelFormat , which you'll want to look over for more information.

Comment: Perfect answer for when you initialise data using a "default" pixel format.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the window (or maybe it's called "surface", it's been a while and it was SDL 1.x), it includes a pixel format specification for drawing on that window, which you should use.